# How execute ipython jupyter code inside MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

There is a Python code that I need to run inside MATLAB. It would calculate using input values from arrays given and calculated before along the MATLAB code. The Python code use Jupyter libraries, and the [base] status of the conda needs to be running on “terminal” inside MATLAB. Does someone have suggestions about how I can run the code? Here is an example of how I am running the code currently on terminal:

(base) user@MacBook Downloads % ipython3 code.py 1 34.4 45 1000

1, 34.4, 45, and 1000 will be four different variables calculated before on MATLAB.

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: You can use `system`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html